# Data Model for web-based video editing

Tags: javascript, video, web, datamodel, video-editing

I'm developing a web video editor that 
users can edit videos through a timeline interface that's similar to the red rectangle part in the following picture.

[image]

To achieve this I think there should be a tree-structured data model in the server side to maintain all the data used for editing operations, as shown in the following diagram.

[image]
Taking the timeline in the interface picture as an example, there is one `TimeLine` object that has one `VideoGroup` sub-object and one `AudioGroup` sub-object. The `VideoGroup` object has a collection of 2 Track objects, namely `Video 1` and `Video 2`. `The AudioGroup` object has 1 Track objects named `Audio 1`. `Video 1`, the first Track object of the `VideoGroup` object has a collection of 4 Media objects, the second Track object `Video 2` has 6. While `Audio 1`, the only one Track object of the `AudioGroup` object doesn't have any.

When it comes to my application, in the back end the data model is used for the application to perform the actual editing operations. In the front end, it should be displayed on the web page in a graphical way like what's shown in the interface picture. In order to achieve this goal, I'm wondering that since there is already a data model in the server end, do I need to create a correspond JavaScript data model in the client side? If not, the front web page need to reload the data model from the back-end every time the user has done the editing operation that modifies it, in order to display its updated version to the end user. Is it OK to go that way?

Comment: can you let me know how did you achieve display UI on frontend side? any lib that you use to render video and timeline in UI?

Comment: Can you please let me know if you have completed this project? Can you please provide me a Github link or something? 'Cuz I am working on a project which is something along similar lines, so studying how you went about this will surely help. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also like to know if you achieved a result for this project UI wise
@BilalShah

Comment: @Noam I was able to achieve the desired result timeline on UI side

Comment: Can you share your results? @BilalShah

Answer (score 0):

A birds eye view, high level answer:

Sounds like your building a Single Page Application. First, your app will load the required video / audio / data via an API that represents the various models/classes of your data structure. In the browser, you will load this data into a frontend framework (Angular, React, Ember or whatever you prefer).

The models will more than likely mirror the data structure you have server side but there may be variations to handle specific frontend concerns.

The frontend framework will render your timeline and handle the various actions that a user makes.

Either through a save action / or periodically, you will send (PUT) updates
back to the server through your API, recording the users changes to the timeline.

Comment: If I understand your answer right, you suggest me to build a correspond data model in the front end using JavaScript. But due to the time constraint for my project, I prefer to not build it as I think it's easier to implementing loading model from server-end rather than constructing two complex data model on both client and server side and writing the code to synchronize them. While I'm not sure about whether my preferable way could bring other big issues for my web application.

Comment: I think that your app, by it's nature will have many user interactions. Your probably going to want a frontend framework to structure these concerns anyway. Have you decided on your preferred technology stack?

Comment: In terms of technology stack, I use ASP.NET and DirectShow.NET API in the server end for video editing. As to the front-end, I use HTML Canvas to display the timeline interface and write pure JavaScript code to handle user events and exchange data with the server. As I don't have much experience in Web development, I can't figure out a better way right now.

Comment: If time is a big issue for you, i understand you may not want to add new tech to your stack. It is certainly possible to write your app with vanilla js. I still think you would be best constructing an API to persist changes made by users from the browser. Otherwise, page reloads are going to cause you all kinds of problems and give a bad user experience of the timeline.